# index tag UITapGestureRecognizer not responive when applied to outlet collection

Tags: swift, uitapgesturerecognizer

When a `UIView` is touched it should move. When the `UIView` is touched nothing happens. All of the `UIView`s are connected in a outlet collection. No constraints are applied in the storyboard. I do not understand why nothing is happening when I touch the `UIView`s. My code is in swift.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet private var cardView: [UIView]!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        for index in cardView.indices  {
            let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapCard(sender: )))

            cardView[index].isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            cardView[index].addGestureRecognizer(tap)
            cardView[index].tag = index
        }
    }

    @objc func tapCard (sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        let clickedView = cardView[sender.view!.tag]
        print("View tapped !" , clickedView )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your iboulet collection work correctly. Try change some property of that views...

And second, does you down through that code on touch and nothing happens, or you just doesn't rich that part of code on touch? thank you

Comment: When I click on the uiview nothining happens but this is what is printed in the debug area.

Comment: View tapped ! <UIView: 0x7fe0aa702d50; frame = (109 361; 240 128); autoresize = RM+BM; tag = 1; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x60000077da70>; layer = <CALayer: 0x600000951c20>>

Comment: so if in debug area printed: "view tapped"... that mean, that tap gesture is works, because you set this action in @objc func tapCard (sender: UITapGestureRecognizer)... Right?